# pyodbc MS Access Driver syntax error but the syntax looks correct

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error, sql-insert

I have 2 tables on an Access database. I need to insert data of column a,b,c from table 2 into column a,b,c of table 1. Here is a python code I wrote to get it done.

```py
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ= G:\dev\TOTAL MAIN DATABASE  OF COMPUTER OF IUB.mdb')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO [TOTAL LIST  OF COMPUTER SET:] (ITEM  DESCRIPTIONS, SUPPLIER, PRODUCT  NUMBER, RECEIVING DATE, WARRANTY  STATUS, SCHOOL/DEPT, PRESENT  LOCATION, PRESENT USER, WORK ORDER NO, UNIT PRICE, REMARKS )
               SELECT 
               ITEM  DESCRIPTIONS, SUPPLIER, PRODUCT  NUMBER, RECEIVING DATE, WARRANTY  STATUS, SCHOOL/DEPT, PRESENT  LOCATION, PRESENT USER, WORK ORDER NO, UNIT PRICE, REMARKS 
               FROM [TOTAL PRINTER FOR ALL]''')
```

I keep getting a syntax error that I am unable to locate.
The error is **pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement**
Maybe someone from here can see the syntax error?
My guess is that the uppercase column names are bothering the driver.

Comment: Are "ITEM DESCRIPTIONS", "PRODUCT NUMBER", "RECEIVING DATE", and "SCHOOL/DEPT" supposed to be column names?  If so, they should be double-quoted.

Comment: now ```cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO [TOTAL LIST  OF COMPUTER SET:] ("ITEM  DESCRIPTIONS", "SUPPLIER", "PRODUCT  NUMBER", "RECEIVING DATE", "WARRANTY  STATUS", "SCHOOL/DEPT", "PRESENT  LOCATION", "PRESENT USER", "WORK ORDER NO", "UNIT PRICE", "REMARKS")
               SELECT 
               "ITEM  DESCRIPTIONS", "SUPPLIER", "PRODUCT  NUMBER", "RECEIVING DATE", "WARRANTY  STATUS", "SCHOOL/DEPT", "PRESENT  LOCATION", "PRESENT USER", "WORK ORDER NO", "UNIT PRICE", "REMARKS"
               FROM [TOTAL PRINTER FOR ALL]''')```
I get **Too few parameters, expected 2**

Comment: They shouldn't be double quoted at all, in Access they should be bracketed

Comment: @ErikA bracketed as in () {} [] ?

Comment: Square brackets, the last one

Comment: @ErikA so table names and column names should all be inside Square brackets?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Yes. changed it, still getting a **Too few parameters. Expected 2** error. But my insert column and select columns are exactly the same.

Comment: ```cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO [TOTAL LIST  OF COMPUTER SET:] ([ITEM  DESCRIPTIONS], [SUPPLIER], [PRODUCT  NUMBER], [RECEIVING DATE], [WARRANTY  STATUS], [SCHOOL/DEPT], [PRESENT  LOCATION], [PRESENT USER], [WORK ORDER NO], [UNIT PRICE], [REMARKS])
               SELECT 
               [ITEM  DESCRIPTIONS], [SUPPLIER], [PRODUCT  NUMBER], [RECEIVING DATE], [WARRANTY  STATUS], [SCHOOL/DEPT], [PRESENT  LOCATION], [PRESENT USER], [WORK ORDER NO], [UNIT PRICE], [REMARKS]
               FROM [TOTAL PRINTER FOR ALL]''')
``` 
For reference.

Comment: Then you probably misspelled 2 fields

Comment: Okay i am having a thorough look now.

Comment: @ErikA: When using pyodbc, double quotes can be used.  Square brackets must be used only when using DAO or in Access' interface itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ= G:\dev\whole.accdb')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO  [TOTAL LIST  OF COMPUTER SET:1] ([ITEM  DESCRIPTIONS], [SUPPLIER], [PRODUCT  NUMBER], [RECEIVING DATE], [WARRANTY  STATUS], [SCHOOL/DEPT], [PRESENT  LOCATION], [PRESENT USER], [WORK ORDER NO], [UNIT PRICE], [REMARKS])
                    SELECT [ITEM  DESCRIPTIONS], [SUPPLIER], [PRODUCT  NUMBER], [RECEIVING DATE], [WARRANTY  STATUS], [SCHOOL/DEPT], [PRESENT  LOCATION], [PRESENT USER], [WORK ORDER NO], [UNIT PRICE], [REMARKS]
                        FROM [ATTENDENCE DEVICE FOR ACCESS CONTROL SYSTEM]''')
try: 
    conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

correct syntax for accessing tables : `[table_name]`
correct syntax for accessing columns : `[column_name]`
Hope this helps.